# recvfrom() socket programming Ubuntu

Tags: c, linux, sockets, ubuntu

I posted a question yesterday and got some helpful feedbacks! So, I fixed a lot of my codes and now the problem I have is to extract data from `recvfrom()` and displaying them in `printf()`, here are my codes:

```
clientAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
clientAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
userIP.s_addr = RespMessage.user[i].ipAddr;
clientAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = userIP.s_addr;

printf("Username FOUND! What do you want to say? \n");
fgets(inMsg, MAX_MSG_LEN, stdin);
chatMsg = (UDPchat_t *)inMsg;

send = sendto(UDP_socketID, chatMsg->message, sizeof(chatMsg->message), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&clientAddr, size_c);
if (send < 0) 
{
       printf("Sending failure : %d", errno);
       continue;
}
else
{
       printf("Message sent!\n");
       continue;
}

outMsgLen = recvfrom(UDP_socketID, outMsg, MAX_MSG_LEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&clientAddr, (socklen_t*)&size_c);
send = gettimeofday(&timeVal, NULL);
curtime = timeVal.tv_sec;
printf("[%ld] Rcvd pkt from: ", outMsgLen);
```

Please help! Thank you..

Comment: What's the question? if you're looking for a code review for working code, you should probably ask on [codereview.se] instead.

Comment: What's the problem here?

Comment: Sorry I did not clarify properly.. My question is how to extract the message out from recvfrom() to display in printf()?

Answer (score 1):

`outMsgLen` are the number of bytes received by `recvfrom`

If you want to display the text:

```
outMsg[outMsgLen] = '\0';
printf("%s\n", outMsg);
```

**EDIT:**

As @nos says there is an overflow risk if `outMsg` is not declared as `char outMsg[MAX_MSG_LEN + 1];`

A better choice would have been to use `strlen(whatever)` in `recvfrom` instead of `MAX_MSG_LEN` to determine the length.

Comment: Okay, I changed them already. I tried running this program then on two different terminals as separate hosts.. My message is sent out without errors, but the other party still couldn't receive anything.. How come?

Comment: @Broccoli Hard to tell from the code you posted. The posted code though requires anyone to send data first, not respond to a single incoming message though. You should learn how to use wireshark to debug messages on the wire (so you can see if messages actually are sent, have the proper addresses, port numbers, content etc.).

Comment: Oh! I understand what you mean. I thought the recvfrom() function takes whatever incoming messages already.. Could you give me some ideas on how to receive messages automatically? Do I have to declare another recvfrom() outside this loop?

Comment: @Broccoli take a look to this excellent [guide](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/index.html)